# How do I change the hitbox of a movie clip in actionscript 3 to not use the bounding box?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, collision

We have an object (mc_robert) that collides with another object (mc_left). When the collision occurs, we have an action take place. What we're trying to figure out is how to change the collision box of the object (mc_robert) so that the objects overlap when the collision detects. We don't want the default collision box of the object (mc_robert). Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated.

This is what we have for our code currently:

```
var numX:Number = 0;
var numY:Number = -2;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
function loop(e:Event)
  {
  mc_robert.y += numY;
  mc_robert.x += numX;
  if (mc_robert.hitTestObject(mc_left))
    {
    numX = -2;
    numY = 0;
    mc_robert.rotation = -90;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For pixel perfect collision convert the shapes into BitmapData and use the BitmapData's Hit-test method.

If you don't want to do the above approach you can use hitTestPoint and create multiple points in a for loop to do the collision.

eg: Haven't tested the following code but the concept is there. This will create a bounding box, or you can use some trig to collide from a circle or custom create the points.

```
for(var y:int = 0;y<2;y++){
     for(var x:int=0;x<2;x++){
        var w:int = mc2.width*x;
        var h:int = mc2.height*y;
        if(mc1.hitTestPoint(mc2.x+w, mc2.y+h, true)){
           trace("collides");
        }
     }
}
```

How ever the solution I would use for the best accuracy would be a BitmapData collision.